# Family Choice for GLM with 0-1 Dependent Variable

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I want to analyze the relationship between the dependent variable "Knowledge_index" (va numeric variable ranging between 0 and 1, both inclusive) and several independent variables (type “factor”, including "Age", "Gender", "Place_birth", "Residence_time", "Education" and "Professional_sector".

```r
str(data$Knowledge_index)
 num [1:430] 0.88 0.63 0.75 0.25 1 1 0.88 0.75 0.88 0 ...
```

The model:

```r
glm1 <- glm(Knowledge_index ~ Age + Gender + Place_birth + Residence_time + 
            Education + Professional_sector, data = data, 
            family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"))
```

Since the dependent variable has values between 0 and 1, I believe that it's correct to use `quasibinomial` distribution with a logit link function (`family = quasibinomial(link = "logit")`). Is this correct or should I use another family?

[image]

Below I add more information about the construction of the index (the dependent variable). This index is constructed from 4 questions asked to the respondent (I1, I2, I3, I4). The calculation is summarized below Knowledge_Index = (0.25 * I1) + (0.25 * I2) + (0.25 * I3) + (0.25 * I4). For example, if the respondent answers all 4 questions correctly, the result would be Knowledge_Index = (0.25 * 1) + (0.25 * 1) + (0.25 * 1) + (0.25 * 1) = 1. If the respondent answers three questions correctly and one incorrectly: Knowledge_index = (0.25 * 1) + (0.25 * 1) + (0.25 * 1) + (0.25 * 0) = 0.75

Comment: I think this should work, but, personally, I've usually used beta regression for this kind of dependent variable. There is a betareg package in R.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this package does not work because the dependent variable values are between 0 and 1, both inclusive. The error message when I tried the betareg package: "invalid dependent variable, all observations must be in (0,1)".

Comment: What is "knowledge index"? If it is something like a score on an exam, there are special models for analyzing these outcomes.

Comment: Also you can use ordinary linear regression. True, some predicted values may lie beyond the range of observable values, but the inference is still valid.

Comment: 1) The "knowledge index" is an index that varies between 0 (no knowledge) and 1 (maximum knowledge) depending on the knowledge of the respondent. I have added more information about the construction of the index above in the question (I hope it is useful). 2) What do you mean by "ordinary linear regression"? In summary, I am not sure which type of family would be most appropriate. Thank you very much!

Comment: How is that knowledge index measured? What about measurement uncertainty?

Comment: Please see the problem description above (below the histogram image). Thanks!